# Google Drive API - Creates duplicate folders

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I am developing a Java program that will upload documents to Google Drive.  I found that if I try to upload to an existing folder, that I have to make sure that it is case sensitive to the existing folder.  If my existing folder is on the Root labelled HDDocs, then I must input the path as "/HDDocs/10/05/01".  Doing this works fine and the files are uploaded to the correct path on Google Drive - as long as I use mu personal gmail account.  As soon as I try to do this on my Google Apps account, a brand new folder is created, also called HDDOcs and the files are loaded into this folder, and not the original.

So on my Google App Drive, I have two root folders labeled HDDocs.

Any feedback would be great.

Answer (score 2):

File and folder names in Google Drive are not unique, so you should't rely on that to identify your targets. Instead, you should always use the unique id.